# CSS: Using nth-child in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I am trying to creat three arrays, and fill them with specific information gathered from each child element of tr.

I keep on getting a syntax error, however the code below works fine when I replace the child element with a number (it just fills the entire array with the same string).

I've been stuck on this for a while, so any syntax help would be much appreciated! Am I approaching this the right way?

---

---

```
var str = new Array ();

for (i =1; i<=5; i++){

str[i] = $("tr:nth-child(i+2) > td.short-desc > a > div > div.col-lg-5.col-         sm-6.hidden-xs > div.pull-left > div > div:nth-child(2) > img ").attr('src')
 }

var pos = new Array ();

for (i=1; i<=5; i++){
pos[i] = str[i+2].search("traveler/");
}

var rating = new Array ();

for (i=1; i<=5; i++){
rating[i] = str[i+2].substring(pos[i+2]+ 9, pos[i+2] +12);
}
```

Comment: `tr:nth-child(i+2)` will never work as you are referencing the variable `i` inside a string constant. That part, at least, would need to be `...tr:nth-child(" + (i+2) + ")...` It would help if you provided sample HTML too, against which we could produce a working example :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - it seems to work and I am now able to fill the array for the first variable, however it's now not filling pos. Am I calling str[i+2] correctly here? When I use  str["+ (i+2) +"]   it still isn't calling properly!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selectors have no access to the surrounding context, so they can't see the variable `i`. You have two options:

1. Calculate the value in the loop and then pass the result to jQuery: `$("tr:nth-child(" + (i+2) + ") > ..."`
2. Get a list of `<tr>` elements, iterate over them and then use a selector on each element.

The second solution look like so:

```
var rows = $('<tr>'); // get all rows as array

for( i=1; i<=5; i++) {
   // search a child of a certain row
   $("td.short-desc > a > div > ...", rows[i+2]);
}
```